# Run Insert SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

How would I run an INSERT SQL query in Microsoft Access?

For Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_UserPurchase (ID, Name) Values (321, Joe)
```

Comment: If your question is about how to use the Access interface, this isn't a programming question. Your query looks fine, except you need single quotes around `Joe`.

Comment: `Joe` should be `'Joe'`... thats it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your query in Access' query designer, then while still in Design View, click "Run" on the ribbon.  (Look for the red explanation point.)

If you want to do it from code, you can use the `.Execute` method of either the DAO database object or the ADO `CurrentProject.Connection` object.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_UserPurchase (ID, [Name])" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES(321, 'Joe');"
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

However, a parameter query would be more flexible (useful for other user names, not just Joe) and prevent SQL injection.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_UserPurchase (ID, [Name])" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES (321, [which_user]);"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strInsert)
' you could read the parameter value from a text box on a form,
' but this example will just hard code Joe
qdf.Parameters("[which_user]").value = "Joe"
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

And there are still other ways to skin this cat.  If none of the suggestions is satisfactory, give us more details about how and where you want to run your `INSERT`.

Comment: thankyou for your reply! I basically want an INSERT query to run when I click a command button in a user form, and the values would come from the text box value. The text box values are also going to be inserted in to different tables, any idea how to achieve this? Also for this project security isn't an issue :)

Comment: Use that last code sample in your command button's click event procedure.  And change the `qdf.Parameters` line to: `qdf.Parameters("[which_user]").value = Me.YourTextBoxNameHere`

Comment: thank you so much! could you help me with one more thing, if i carry out a SELECT query using the same code layout, how would i then turn the result of that query (being one result as output) into a parameter to be used in a seperate INSERT query

Comment: If you want to `SELECT` only a single value, consider using `DLookup` instead.  That's what it was designed for.  Check the Access help topic.  Submit a new question if you need help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote literals in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_UserPurchase (ID, Name) VALUES (321, 'Joe')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think name field is `VarChar`(or some string value at **DB**) so its mean your query should be

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_UserPurchase (ID, Name) Values(321, 'Joe');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (1, 'xyz')`

Please let me know, if that worked for you.

Good Luck