# Insert Into SQL not working

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, insert-into

I have a table named cpns with fields as C_Bk_No (Coupon book number), St_No (starting coupon number) and End_No (number of the last coupon) all integers.

I have initiated the table with first record as 1, 1, 25.

I am trying to get the system insert new rows with cpn number + 1, start_No + 25 and End_No + 25 as the new record on clicking a button (Command13) on the form.

Thus, the expected second record should have cpn_bk_no = 2, St_No = 26, End_No = 50.

I am not sure why the following SQL is not working:

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim CbkNo As Long
    Dim StNo As Long
    Dim EndNo As Long

    CbkNo = Me![C_bk_No].Value + 1
    StNo = Me![St_No].Value + 25
    EndNo = Me![End_No].Value + 25

    Sql = "Insert Into cpns ([C_bk_No], [St_No], [End_No]); Values (CBkNo, StNo, EndNo))"

    CurrentDb.Execute Sql

End Sub
```

Every time I click the button, it says "Run time error 3061, Too few parameters: Expected 3." and the line "CurrentDb.Execute Sql" is highlighted in yellow.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: What are you trying to acheive ? What is the error message ? What is the table cpns format ? What database do you use ?

Comment: Remove `;` from the INSERT command?

Comment: Hi, I removed the semicolon but still not helping. It says "Run time error '3137' Missing semicolon at end of SQL statement". I am using MS Access 2007. Thanks.

Comment: The line "CurrentDb.Execute Sql" is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Use parameters as specified in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780594/2224701

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Insert SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778917/run-insert-sql-queries)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know where to begin with this, but the basic problem you're facing is that you've typed the names of your variables into the string. Unlike some other languages, vb doesn't look at your string contents and think "oh, he's typed a variable name into that string, I'll jut swap it for the value currently in the variable"

There are other problems with this code too, but not quite so fundamental as that. I'd genuinely recommend you throw all that code away and follow this tutorial instead, about how to access a database in one of the ways Microsoft recommends:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx

Even if you're not making a win forms app the concepts there inside can be applied to all kinds of app

Answer (score 0):

This semicolon is wrong. Semicolons are use to separate sql statements from each other.

```
Insert Into cpns ([C_bk_No], [St_No], [End_No]) **;** Values (CBkNo, StNo, EndNo)
```

remove it and put it at the and it will work:

```
Insert Into cpns ([C_bk_No], [St_No], [End_No]) Values (CBkNo, StNo, EndNo);
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the semicolon but still not helping. It says "Run time error '3137' Missing semicolon at end of SQL statement". I am using MS Access 2007. Thanks.      
The line "CurrentDb.Execute Sql" is highlighted in yellow. – S. Sandip 25 secs ago   edit