# can't insert value from a form into lookup field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form that insert data into a table , the problem is I can't insert value from my combo box into a table field which is ( lookup field) this field should store an integer (ID) that I lookup from a different table.
the error I have is
[image]

here is my code :

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tblStocks([Stock Code], [Stock Name], [Stock Keeper1]) VALUES('" & txtCode & "','" & txtName & "'," & cmbStockKeeper1.Value & ")")
```

Comment: Have you turned [SetWarnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setwarnings) off?

Comment: aaah ... I look stupid right now :) , anyways what is the right syntax cause I have a sql statement error

Comment: I edited the post and added the error message , thank you for replying

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection - for example, it will break if one of those textboxes contains an apostrophe. You should be using Parameters instead.

Comment: well this insert statement gave me a headache so if you could please give me an example for insert statement with parameters

Comment: I tried this solution but now i have a new error  i will edit the post

Comment: Parameters example: [Run Insert SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13780594/77335)

Comment: i want to clarify that cmbStockKeeper1 is the lookup field from type Long , i tried to msgbox the typeName of the input of the form and it's long so the types shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Now it seems you have a key violation error.  That can happen if you have a unique index and any of the values you're attempting to insert duplicate those in existing records.  It can also happen when you have a relationship which enforces referential integrity and you attempt to insert values which don't satisfy that requirement.

Comment: thank you so much for your answers I will look that up and check my tables

Comment: you are right i just edited the field and removed indexed from them and it worked, thank you for you answer can you please put it as an answer so anyone can use it later

Answer (score 1):

The problem simply was caused by my table design as I made the field (Stock Keeper1) indexed with no duplicate and I forgot about it, so the message was due to me trying to insert a value was already given to another record